# Impossible to un-star/un-pin messages for long list

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

I think there is a lack of tools to un-star messages. Currently, there is a way to do this: to select the corresponding link in the list of recently starred messages:

[image]

But the problem is: if the list of messages can not be shown because of it's length, then it's impossible to un-star messages that are below starred messages area:

[image]

As you can see, the list is limited to only those messages that fit on the screen (because of the list's size). And there's no scrollbar to view messages off the bottom of the screen - thus, operate on it is impossible.

This is mostly about low-resolution screens, but I think with sufficient starred/pinned messages this may be a problem at normal resolutions too. I think either a scrollbar should be added, or alternative way to operate on starred messages should exist (unless it already exists and I've missed that - but even if so, fixing of current starred/pinned messages is needed).

Comment: also, sometimes, I see `show 5 more` after starred and when I click it, some new starred messages are shown, and some of them goes behind the bottom bar of stackoverflow chat. These are non-scrollable and I am also not able to see, those other 5, which I just showed.

Comment: Yes, right my case (as you can see on 2-nd screenshot, I've already clicked _"show X more"_)

Comment: this is a bug, so you might wanna consider adding a tag [tag:bug] to your question, rather than [tag:feature-request]

Comment: I'm not sure if it is only a bug, but edited

Comment: I’d say it’s a feature request as the functionality exists but there simply isn’t a button for it on the long star list.